# Mobile application with sql databases

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I am currently working on a mobile application, I have linked the application to the sql type database by Azure SQL Database Now I am in the trial phase and the program is working fine but I have not done REST services, I linked the application directly to the database through the connection strings
  Note that the application serves a specific category of users, do you recommend this work, or do REST and API services.
Please Help

Comment: exposing your SQL db directly to the internet is generally a HORRIBLE idea and should be avoided

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST model was created for this. If you want to make your application available to the public, anyone can try to decompile your application, and if they can, they will have access to your database if you are using a connection string. With access to the database, they can delete records and tables, for example, tasks that your API will not allow.

Comment: Thank you so much .
I expected this, but I wasn't sure